# UIATarget.setLocationWithOptions course not applying

Tags: javascript, ios, mapkit, core-location, ui-automation

I'm attempting to automate the path of a user via UI Automation. Ideally, the user location in an `MKMapView` would update according to the list of waypoints I've explicated in the automation script:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

var waypoints = [
    {location: {latitude: 37.33170, longitude: -122.03020}, options: {course: 180}},
    {location: {latitude: 37.33170, longitude: -122.03022}, options: {course: 180}},
    {location: {latitude: 37.33170, longitude: -122.03025}, options: {course: 180}},
    {location: {latitude: 37.33170, longitude: -122.03027}, options: {course: 180}},
    {location: {latitude: 37.33170, longitude: -122.03030}, options: {course: 180}},
    {location: {latitude: 37.33170, longitude: -122.03032}, options: {course: 180}},
    {location: {latitude: 37.33170, longitude: -122.03035}, options: {course: 180}},
    {location: {latitude: 37.33170, longitude: -122.03037}, options: {course: 180}},
    {location: {latitude: 37.33170, longitude: -122.03040}, options: {course: 180}}
];

for (var waypointIndex = 0; waypointIndex < waypoints.length; waypointIndex++)
{
    if (waypointIndex == 0)
        target.delay(5);

    var waypoint = waypoints[waypointIndex];
    target.setLocationWithOptions(waypoint.location, waypoint.options);

    target.delay(1);

    if (waypointIndex == (waypoints.length - 1))
        waypointIndex = 0;
}
```

The location portion applies without issue, and the user's indicator moves along the path. However, the course option doesn't seem to be doing anything. I've tried `90`, `180`, `-90`, `3.14`, and `1.57` as values for the option, to no avail.

I've also tried adding in the `speed: 8` parameter to `options`, with no change.

Seeing as how this appears to be the [only way to simulate headings at all](http://www.cardinalsolutions.com/blogs/mobile/2013/02/testing_a_location-a.html), and that the [`course` option is totally valid and documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/UIATargetClass/UIATargetClass.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIATarget/setLocationWithOptions), it's frustrating that it isn't working.

**Annoying hacky workaround:** If you simulation location (via GPX file), on the physical device, the device's rotation works. This way you can simulate a route and get rotation.

Comment: Don't you have to supply the speed of motion as well?

Comment: Not sure why I'd have to, but I'll give it a shot!

Comment: My thinking is that you cannot have course without actually moving, and that the environment does not calculate the speed for you if you just update the location.

Comment: No dice, brother. Speed doesn't seem to affect course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coordinates like this work for me in instruments:

```
{location:{longitude:2.105528,latitude:41.414359}, options:{speed:20, course: 290, altitude:200, horizontalAccuracy:10, verticalAccuracy:15}}
```

Give a try to horizontal and vertical accuracy, and maybe even altitude.

Good luck!